# Sort List by alphabetical order

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to sort a list by alphabetical order and tried porting something i had in javascript to flutter. But it gives me an exception on String that it does not have the instance method '<'. I hope someone can help me fix this. Because i have no clue how to correct this issue.

```
data.sort((a, b) {
            var aName = a['name'].toLowerCase();
            var bName = b['name'].toLowerCase();
            return ((aName < bName) ? -1 : ((aName > bName) ? 1 : 0));
        });
```

I get this exception:

```
E/flutter (16823): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (16823): NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance method '<'.
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

`<` and `>` is usually a shortcut to a `compareTo` method.

just use that method instead.

```
data.sort((a, b) {
  return a['name'].toLowerCase().compareTo(b['name'].toLowerCase());
});
```

Answer (score 26):

I found the best way to sort a list alphabetically is this:

```
      List.sort((a, b) => a.toString().compareTo(b.toString()));
```

Comment: `.toLowerCase()` should always be considered

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to Remi's answer, I extracted this as a Function.

```dart
typedef Sort = int Function(dynamic a, dynamic b);
typedef SortF = Sort Function(String sortField);

SortF alphabetic = (String sortField) => (a, b){
  return a[sortField].toLowerCase().compareTo(b[sortField].toLowerCase());
};

SortF number = (String sortField) => (a, b) {
      return a[sortField].compareTo(b[sortField]);
    };
```

with this you can write.

```dart
list.sort(alphabetic('name')); //replace name with field name

list.sort(number('name')); //replace name with field name
```

Answer (score 7):

```
List.sort((a, b) => a.toString().compareTo(b.toString()));
```

The above code code works, but if you use  the above code, it will show capital letters first. That's why you have to convert them all to lowercase inside the sort extension.

```
List.sort((a, b) => a.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toLowerCase()));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
void main() {
  List users = [
    {
      "name": "Abhishek",
      "age": 21,
    },
    {
      "name": "Raj",
      "age": 22,
    },
    {
      "name": "Rajesh",
      "age": 23,
    },
    {
      "name": "Aakash",
      "age": 24,
    }
  ];

  users.sort((a, b) => a["name"].compareTo(b["name"]));
  print(users);
}
```

Output:

```
[{name: Aakash, age: 24}, {name: Abhishek, age: 21}, {name: Raj, age: 22}, {name: Rajesh, age: 23}]
```

Answer (score 2):

late answer, i had a similar situation and here is how i solved it

```
     String a = 'towNnpBiDHRehMh4FhYAYShVFr62';
  String b = 'Yjeq9bA0spdZGmqlbr4J663LyvC3';
  String c = "RdeQo32uUwX3ftBeGm0nFChkzE52";
//if you try to sort the strings without converting them toLowercase ir uppercase you will get different results.
  List<String> _myBranchListName = [
    a.toLowerCase(),
    b.toLowerCase(),
    c.toLowerCase(),
  ];

  _myBranchListName.sort();
//if you want to add to strings from the result
  var userId = "${_myBranchListName[0]}" + "${_myBranchListName[1]}";
  print(userId);

  print(_myBranchListName);
```