# Sorting Lexicographically in Dart

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

Firebase Database sorts results lexicographically, and I have found no way to preserve this sort in Dart.

How would one sort lexicographically in Dart, or preserve the order provided by Firebase Database?

Comment: Since the sort happens on the server, and the code in Flutter uses the same underlying SDK, the behavior should be the same in Flutter as it is in other SDKs. If that's not the case for you, edit your question to include the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: make a bunch of entries on firebase, do onValue read, they are not in the same order compared to doing the same operation in a JS client. Put them in a list and sort using a.compareTo(b) and they don't put them in the same order. That said, the question is less about Firebase, and more about sorting Lexicographically in Dart

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: [Sort List by alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675055/sort-list-by-alphabetical-order)

```
  List<String> input = ["b", "a", "c", "aa"];
  print(input.toString());

  input.sort((a, b) {
    return a.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toLowerCase());
  });
  print(input.toString());  // [a, aa, b, c]
```