# Sort a list of objects in Flutter (Dart) by property value

Tags: list, flutter, sorting, dart

How to sort a list of objects by the alphabetical order of one of its properties (Not the name but the actual value the property holds)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort a list of strings in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888206/how-can-i-sort-a-list-of-strings-in-dart)

Comment: @RichardHeap yes the solution does answer my question but the question is asked differently I guess. Thanks for your help!

Comment: i wrote an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59350472/10409567

Answer (score 465, accepted):

You can pass a comparison function to [`List.sort`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/List/sort.html).

```
someObjects.sort((a, b) => a.someProperty.compareTo(b.someProperty));
```

Comment: how do you reverse sort it

Comment: To reverse it you could do `b.someProperty.compareTo(a.someProperty)`. Or sort it and then use `.reversed`.

Comment: To reverse, just use (b,a) instead of (a,b). It's worth notinng that compareTo returns 1, 0 or -1 if you want to do more advanced sorts.

Answer (score 60):

In general, you can provide a custom comparison function to [`List.sort`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/sort.html).

```dart
/// Desired relation | Result
/// -------------------------------------------
///           a < b  | Returns a negative value.
///           a == b | Returns 0.
///           a > b  | Returns a positive value.
///
int mySortComparison(SomeClass a, SomeClass b) {
  final propertyA = someProperty(a);
  final propertyB = someProperty(b);
  if (propertyA < propertyB) {
    return -1;
  } else if (propertyA > propertyB) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

list.sort(mySortComparison);
```

If you're sorting some custom class you own, you alternatively could make your class implement the [`Comparable`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Comparable-class.html) interface:

```dart
class MyCustomClass implements Comparable<MyCustomClass> {
  ...

  @override
  int compareTo(MyCustomClass other) {
    if (someProperty < other.someProperty) {
      return -1;
    } else if (someProperty > other.someProperty) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

and then you can use `list.sort()` directly without supplying a callback.

Note that if you're sorting by a single property that already implements the `Comparable` interface, implementing the comparison functions is much simpler.  For example:

```dart
class MyCustomClass implements Comparable<MyCustomClass> {
  ...

  @override
  int compareTo(MyCustomClass other) =>
    someProperty.compareTo(other.someProperty);
}
```

---

### Reversing

If you want to reverse the sort order, you can:

- Make your comparison function return a value with the opposite sign.
- Alternatively just explicitly reverse the list after sorting:

  ```dart
  list = (list..sort()).reversed.toList();
  ```

---

### Sorting by multiple properties (a.k.a. subsorting)

There are a variety of ways to sort by multiple properties.

- A general way is to perform a *stable* sort for each property in reverse order of importance.  For example, if you want to sort names primarily by surname and then subsort within surnames by given name, then you would first sort by given names, and then perform a stable sort by surname.   See below for how to perform a stable sort.
- Alternatively, you could sort with a comparison function that itself checks multiple properties.  For example:

  ```dart
  class Name {
    Name({String? surname, String? givenName})
      : surname = surname ?? "",
        givenName = givenName ?? "";

    final String surname;
    final String givenName;
  }

  int compareNames(Name name1, Name name2) {
    var comparisonResult = name1.surname.compareTo(name2.surname);
    if (comparisonResult != 0) {
       return comparisonResult;
    }
    // Surnames are the same, so subsort by given name.
    return name1.givenName.compareTo(name2.givenName);
  }
  ```
- [`package:collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) provides [an extension to chain comparison functions](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/ComparatorExtension/then.html) so that combining them is a bit more straightforward and less error-prone:

  ```dart
  import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

  int compareSurnames(Name name1, Name name2) =>
      name1.surname.compareTo(name2.surname);

  int compareGivenNames(Name name1, Name name2) =>
      name1.givenName.compareTo(name2.givenName);

  final compareNames = compareSurnames.then(compareGivenNames);
  ```
- My [`dartbag`](https://pub.dev/packages/dartbag) package also provides a [`compareIterables`](https://pub.dev/documentation/dartbag/latest/comparable/compareIterables.html) function that allows comparing `List`s of property values in order of importance:

  ```dart
  import 'package:dartbag/collection.dart';

  int compareNames(Name name1, Name name2) =>
    compareIterables(
      [name1.surname, name1.givenName],
      [name2.surname, name2.givenName],
    );
  ```

---

### Okay, I want a stable sort

`List.sort` is *not* guaranteed to be a stable sort.  If you need a stable sort, [`package:collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) provides [`insertionSort`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/insertionSort.html) and [`mergeSort`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/insertionSort.html) implementations that are stable.

---

### But comparing might be expensive

Suppose you have a custom comparison function that looks something like:

```dart
int compareMyCustomClass(MyCustomClass a, MyCustomClass b) {
  var a0 = computeValue(a);
  var b0 = computeValue(b);
  return a0.compareTo(b0);
}
```

The sorting process might call `computeValue` multiple times for the same object, which is particularly wasteful if `computeValue()` is expensive.  In such cases, a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) could be faster (at the expense of using more memory).  This approach maps your objects to directly sortable keys, sorts those keys, and extracts the original objects. (This is how Python's `sort` and `sorted` functions work.)

Here's one possible implementation:

```dart
class _SortableKeyPair<T, K extends Comparable<Object>>
    implements Comparable<_SortableKeyPair<T, K>> {
  _SortableKeyPair(this.original, this.key);

  final T original;
  final K key;

  @override
  int compareTo(_SortableKeyPair<T, K> other) => key.compareTo(other.key);
}

/// Returns a sorted *copy* of [items] according to the computed sort key.
List<E> sortedWithKey<E, K extends Comparable<Object>>(
  Iterable<E> items,
  K Function(E) toKey,
) {
  final keyPairs = [
    for (var element in items) _SortableKeyPair(element, toKey(element)),
  ]..sort();

  return [
    for (var keyPair in keyPairs) keyPair.original,
  ];
}

void main() {
  final list = <MyCustomClass>[ ... ];
  final sorted = sortedWithKeys(list, computeValue);
}
```

My [`dartbag`](https://pub.dev/packages/dartbag) package provides such a [`sortWithKey`](https://pub.dev/documentation/dartbag/latest/collection/SortWithKeyExtension/sortWithKey.html) function (and also a [`sortWithAsyncKey`](https://pub.dev/documentation/dartbag/latest/collection/SortWithKeyExtension/sortWithAsyncKey.html) function if the key needs to be generated asynchronously).

Comment: I was just thinking when I got to "but comparisons might be expensive" something like "I wonder how the author will approach this?"  And there it was again. :)

Answer (score 49):

If you want to sort the object "objects" by the property "name" do something like this

```
objects.sort((a, b) {
  return a.value['name'].toString().toLowerCase().compareTo(b.value['name'].toString().toLowerCase());
});
```

Answer (score 25):

**Immutable** extension `sortedBy` for List.

```
extension MyIterable<E> on Iterable<E> {
  Iterable<E> sortedBy(Comparable key(E e)) =>
      toList()..sort((a, b) => key(a).compareTo(key(b)));
}
```

And use

```
list.sortedBy((it) => it.name);
```

Comment: Pay attention for dartx library. It is very popular and has a lot of useful extensions, mostly designed like in Kotlin.

Answer (score 22):

Here is my contribution to this good question. If someone is facing difficulty to understand how the @Nate Bosch answer is working & you want to sort your custom model class list then you can do this way.

**1. You have to implement `Comparable` abstract class in your model class.**
It has the method `compareTo` which you have to override.
For example, I have this `StudentMarks` model class which has marks property in it.

```
class StudentMarks implements Comparable {
  int marks;

  StudentMarks({
    this.marks,
  });


  @override
  int compareTo(other) {

    if (this.marks == null || other == null) {
      return null;
    }

    if (this.marks < other.marks) {
      return 1;
    }

    if (this.marks > other.marks) {
      return -1;
    }

    if (this.marks == other.marks) {
      return 0;
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

**2. Now you can call `compareTo` method inside the `sort` method.**

```
void _sortStudents({bool reversed: false}) {
    _students.sort((a, b) {
      return a.compareTo(b);
    });

    if (reversed) {
      _students = _students.reversed.toList();
    }

    setState(() {});
  }
```

Refer to this link you want to know more about the `Comparable` class

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Comparable-class.html

Comment: If you're sorting a list of objects that properly implements `Comparable`, you shouldn't need to explicitly call `List.sort` with a callback; it should be automatic.

Answer (score 14):

Its worked for me:

```
myList..sort((a, b) => a.name.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.name.toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30835727)

Answer (score 11):

Using `Comparator`function, sort `Users` by `id`.

```
Comparator<UserModel> sortById = (a, b) => a.id.compareTo(b.id);
users.sort(sortById);
```

Now we can sort it in reversed/descending order.

```
users = users.reversed.toList();
```

Comment: This is simple and easy to use for classes.

Answer (score 11):

To sort it in reverse order :

```
list.sort((a, b) {
          return b.status.toLowerCase().compareTo(a.status.toLowerCase());
        });
```

Answer (score 9):

What's more, you can use **`Comparable.compare`** for more clear, for example:

```dart
class _Person {
  final int age;
  final String name;
  _Person({required this.age, required this.name});
}

void _test() {
  final array = [
    _Person(age: 10, name: 'Dean'),
    _Person(age: 20, name: 'Jack'),
    _Person(age: 30, name: 'Ben'),
  ];

  // ascend with age
  // Dean Jack Ben
  array.sort((p1, p2) {
    return Comparable.compare(p1.age, p2.age);
  });

  // decend with age
  // Ben Jack Dean
  array.sort((p1, p2) {
    return Comparable.compare(p2.age, p1.age);
  });

  // ascend with name
  // Ben Dean Jack
  array.sort((p1, p2) {
    return Comparable.compare(p1.name, p2.name);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Similar to @pavel-shorokhovs answer, but strongly typed:

```
extension IterableExtensions<T> on Iterable<T> {

  Iterable<T> sortBy<TSelected extends Comparable<TSelected>>(
      TSelected Function(T) selector) =>
  toList()..sort((a, b) => selector(a).compareTo(selector(b)));

  Iterable<T> sortByDescending<TSelected extends Comparable<TSelected>>(
      TSelected Function(T) selector) =>
  sortBy(selector).toList().reversed;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

i had fpgrowth machine learning output/result with each element of list contains another list and frequency field i was to sort by frequency in descending order so i used a bit of recursion for that try it might work i know i am late but i am posting maybe someone else could benefit.

```
 sort(List<FrequentItem> fqItems) {
    int len = fqItems.length;
    if(len==2){
      if(fqItems[0].frequency>fqItems[1].frequency){
        sortedItems.add(fqItems[0]);
        sortedItems.add(fqItems[1]);
      }else{
        sortedItems.add(fqItems[1]);
        sortedItems.add(fqItems[0]);
      }
      return;
    }else{
      FrequentItem max = fqItems[0];
      int index =0;
      for(int i=0;i<len-2;i++){
        if(max.frequency<fqItems[i+1].frequency){
          max = fqItems[i+1];
          index = i+1;
        }
      }
      sortedItems.add(max);
      fqItems.removeAt(index);
      sort(fqItems);
    }


  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Add compareTo method to class:

```
class Student {
  String? name;
  int? age;

  Student({this.name, this.age});

  int getAge() {
    if (age == null) return 0;
    return age!;
  }

  @override
  int compareTo(Student other) {
    var a = getAge();
    var b = other.getAge();

    if (a < b) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a > b) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Step 2: Sorting your list:

- By ascending:

  studentList.sort((a, b) {
  return a.compareTo(b);
  });
- By descending:

  studentList.sort((a, b) {
  return b.compareTo(a);
  });

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is looking to sort by multiple fields the following example would work. The example is a bit raw, but the logic is simple. First, we are sorting by the league id (smaller ids first) and then sorting the elements with the same league id by the timestamp.

```
final fixtures = snapshop.data!.docs..sort((a, b) {
  final leagueCompare = a['league_id'].compareTo(b['league_id']);
                                                    
  if (leagueCompare == 0) {
    return a['timestamp'].compareTo(b['timestamp']);
  }

  return leagueCompare;
});
```