# Sort a dart list based on constructor parameter

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, flutter, dart

I have defined a class like this,

```
class Person {
  final int id,
  final String name,
  final String email,
  final int age,

  Person({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.age});
}
```

I have a list of Person like,

```
List<Person> persons;
```

Now, I need to sort this list as per its constructor parameters like id or age. How can I do that?

Comment: Post snippet of what you have tried already.

Comment: I want a way to do this, what I have tried is to save those parameters in another list and sort persons list with reference to the parameter list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a list of objects in Flutter (Dart) by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53547997/sort-a-list-of-objects-in-flutter-dart-by-property-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do that with [sort](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/List/sort.html) method.

Here's a simple example, sorting the list by the Person name:

```
class Person {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final int age;

  Person({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.age});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "Person $name";
  }
}

void main () {
  List<Person> people = new List();
  people
    ..add(Person(name: "B"))
    ..add(Person(name: "A"))
    ..add(Person(name: "D"))
    ..add(Person(name: "C"));

  people.sort((p1, p2) => p1.name.compareTo(p2.name));
  print(people);
}
```

Output:

```
[Person A, Person B, Person C, Person D]
```