# Flutter: How to sort a list by two or more fields?

Tags: list, sorting, flutter

I have a list of objects that contain a few properties each.

Object.name = "Some string"
Object.age = some int
*List l = [{"Peter", 25}, {"Peter", 22}, {"John", 26}, {"Max", 26}]*

I can't find anywhere how I can sort the list so it looks like this:
*[{"John", 26}, {"Max", 26}, {"Peter", 22}, {"Peter", 25}]*

Ascending on "name" and then, if same value, ascending on "age".

List.sort seems to not have an option for multiple fields and always sort by the one field provided.

Can someone please give me a pointer?

Thanks

Comment: @diegoveloper The linked answer for being a duplicate doesn't answer the question on sorting on more than one property.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53549197/666221 , you have the object `a` and `b`, then you can use the properties you want to compare the values

Comment: This is not a duplicate, that question does not answer mine.
I know how to use List.sort. But List.sort does not seem to have a method to sort by x then y.
Reopen the question please.

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53549197/666221 , you have both objects, why don't you compare by the properties you want?

Comment: Because I need to check for one first and the other one next. 
The .sort only allows for one property. 
If I am not getting the point, would you care to show how you are proposing I do this? 
Thanks!

Comment: I have an answer to the question that @QCIHDTM asked. Please just reopen so you can understand it is not a duplicate

Comment: You can find the answer (and possible solution) here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58418440/1737201

Comment: @mezoni has a good solution if you have access to that API. Here is my solution that I'm not allowed to post using the basic Comparable interface. https://gist.github.com/DFreds/17db0c3f8165839b7202a8ce63e5e7df

Comment: Correct - whoever closed this was not paying attention.  Please remove the duplicate tag.