# flutter finding out the title of the ToDoItem that has the highest price

Tags: flutter, dart, numbers, highest

**To-Do App**

```
class ToDoItem{
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  final int price;
  final IconData icon;
  final String todoListId;

  const ToDoItem({
    @required this.color,
    @required this.id,
    @required this.todoListId,
    @required this.price,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.icon,
  });}
```

I am trying to find
the title of the  ToDoItem  which    has  the highest price

And the  ToDoItem is being added to this:

```
List<ToDoItem> toDo= [];
```

Comment: You can make a method of the Todo Class to get the highest price by storing the copy of the List in memory and then get the highest price..

Comment: i am already storing the toDoItem to the devices storage

Comment: i have answered below , do mark it as an answer if it helps

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53547997/sort-a-list-of-objects-in-flutter-dart-by-property-value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void main(){
  

  List<ToDoItem> _myList = [];
  _myList.add(ToDoItem('10',100));
  
  _myList.add(ToDoItem('30',400));
  _myList.add(ToDoItem('40',2));
  
  _myList.add(ToDoItem('20',200));
  
  _myList.sort((a,b)=>a.price.compareTo(b.price));
  
  for(ToDoItem items in _myList)
    print(items.id + ',' + items.price.toString());
}

  class ToDoItem{
  final String id;
  final int price;

  const ToDoItem(
   this.id,
   this.price,
  );
  }
```

This is the code which i used in dart to sort your list . YOu could use the sorting logic  from in here . it sorts your list in ascending order acc to price .