# Flutter sort list by value

Tags: list, sorting, flutter

how i can sort my List by one of my values from list?

here is a example of my list

```
  List data = [
    {'name': 'Example1', 'value1': 10, 'value2': 0},
    {'name': 'Example2', 'value1': 0, 'value2': 10},
    {'name': 'Example3', 'value1': 15, 'value2': 5},
    {'name': 'Example4', 'value1': 22.5, 'value2': 10},
];
```

and so I call it

```
           Column(
            children: data.map((info) {
          return Container(
            child: SizedBox(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text(info['name'],),
                  Text(info['value1'],),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }).toList())
```

this is how my list is listed from top to bottom

how can i sort it by value?

How can I hide an entry if the value is 0?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a list of objects in Flutter (Dart) by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53547997/sort-a-list-of-objects-in-flutter-dart-by-property-value)

Comment: The documentation also gives an example: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/sort.html

Comment: that doesn't help me any further. my example is completely different

Comment: Really? It looks exactly the same to me. If it is different, can you please explain how it is different? Can you please detail your question to explain what you want more clearly? What should `data` look like after sorting?

Comment: there is a completely different code in the link, i need it with my code example!

after sorting it should just be a list as it is without sorting, only that the entries with the value 0 should be hidden

Comment: ...There is no code in the question I linked. It asks about sorting a list of objects by a property value, which is exactly what you want to do. Or if it is not what you want to do, please edit your question to make it clear what you want to do.

Comment: no, but the answers to the question yes contain code examples, which do not help me any further because i am still a beginner i need an example that fits my code exactly

Comment: The accepted answer contains only one line of code: `someObjects.sort((a, b) => a.someProperty.compareTo(b.someProperty));`. Just replace `someObjects` with `data` and `someProperty` with `name` or `value1` or `value2` or whatever it is you want to sort according to.

Comment: i try this

const List<List<dynamic>> data.sort((a, b) => a.value1.compareTo(b.someProperty)); = [
    {'name': 'Example1', 'value1': 10, 'value2': 0},
    {'name': 'Example2', 'value1': 0, 'value2': 10},
    {'name': 'Example3', 'value1': 15, 'value2': 5},
    {'name': 'Example4', 'value1': 22.5, 'value2': 10},
];

but have errors dont end with a return

Comment: You forgot to replace `b.someProperty` with `b.value1`.

Comment: have replace now but have errors

Comment: i update my list its not dynamic its normal list but the code not work with my list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list.sort() takes a comparator function. A comparator takes two values from the list and compares them to see if swapping is required. Based on what you return, you can control how the lists get sorted. When a positive value is returned, swapping occurs otherwise not.

In your case, let's say you want to sort using value1 in increasing order. You need to tell the comparator to return a positive value when a > b. If you want decreasing order, return a positive value when b > a:

```
List data = [
    {'name': 'Example1', 'value1': 15},
    {'name': 'Example2', 'value1': 10},
    {'name': 'Example3', 'value1': 5},
    {'name': 'Example4', 'value1': 0},
];
  
// sort in place w.r.t. value1
// CompareTo method just returns first value - second value in case of double
// Try returning b['value1'].compareTo(a['value1']) or b['value1'] - a['value1'] and the result should be in descending order w.r.t value1 property.
 
data.sort((a,b) => a['value1'].compareTo(b['value1'])); // You can also write a['value1'] - b['value1']
print(data.toString());
 
// To filter (remove all those elements whose value1 is 0)
List filtered = data.where((a) => a['value1'] != 0).toList(); // Where method takes a function which should return true if you want to keep the item in the filtered list.
print(filtered.toString()); // filtered is the new list with all those elements removed.
```

and here is the output:

```
[{name: Example4, value1: 0}, {name: Example3, value1: 5}, {name: Example2, value1: 10}, {name: Example1, value1: 15}]
[{name: Example3, value1: 5}, {name: Example2, value1: 10}, {name: Example1, value1: 15}]
```

---

Update:

You can use the filter like this:

```
Column(
        children: data
        .where((d) => d['value1'] != 0) // <----- Here :)
        .map((info) {
      return Container(
        child: SizedBox(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Text(info['name'],),
              Text(info['value1'],),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }).toList())
```