# Dart compare and sort List of Map?

Tags: sorting, dictionary, dart

I am trying to sort the list of Map<String, dynamic> I have.

The data looks like the following:

```
[ 
     {
        orderedDate1: [itemsHere...], // The date that I am trying to compare and sort
        Total: 123.00,
    }, 
    {
        orderedDate2: [itemsHere...], // The date that I am trying to compare and sort
        Total: 223.00,
    },.....
]
```

I have look into things like SplayTreeMap but that seems to work for only 1 key in the dictionary? As in, I only want to compare the `orderedDate` key and not the `Total` key but my code keeps on comparing both

The below is what I have tried:

```
    var sorted = SplayTreeMap<String, dynamic>.from(orderData, (a, b) {
      return a.compareTo(b);
    }); // Didn't work for me

    order.data().keys.toList()..sort(); //Didn't work for me
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a list of objects in Flutter (Dart) by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53547997/sort-a-list-of-objects-in-flutter-dart-by-property-value)

Comment: If you're trying to sort the `List`, using `SplayTreeMap`s won't help you.  A `SplayTreeMap` sorts the entries in the *map*.

Comment: Do you want to sort the *list of maps*, or do you want to sort the *ordered data* lists inside the maps? Your question seems to say both. If the former, how do you want to compare the lists of items against each other?