# Dart - How do you multi level sort on a list<T>

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to sort a list of List

I know you can sort by using `_cartItems.sort((a, b) => a.code.compareTo(b.code));`  but I am trying to sort by `group` then by `code`. More of a similar feature like MS Excel multi level sorting.

to hack this I tried this and it seemed to work fine on some cases, but still not very stable.

```
_cartItems.sort((a, b) => a.code.compareTo(b.code));
_cartItems.sort((a, b) => a.group.compareTo(b.group));
```

for example, in cases where there is only a single group, it will do weird things and sort `6,2,3,4,5`, etc.

Any way to multi-sort?

class CartItems:

```
class CartItem {
  String qty;
  final String code;
  final String desc;
  final String invt;
  final String codealt;
  final String descalt;
  final String group;
  final String price;
  final String disc1;
  String globalPrice;
  String total;
  bool isSelected;

  CartItem(
      this.qty,
      this.code,
      this.desc,
      this.invt,
      this.codealt,
      this.descalt,
      this.group,
      this.price,
      this.disc1,
      this.globalPrice,
      this.total,
      {this.isSelected = false});

  CartItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : qty = json['qty'],
        code = json['code'],
        desc = json['desc'],
        invt = json['invt'],
        codealt = json['codealt'],
        descalt = json['descalt'],
        group = json['group'],
        price = json['price'],
        disc1 = json['disc1'],
        globalPrice = json['globalPrice'],
        total = json['total'],
        isSelected = false;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "qty": this.qty,
      "code": this.code,
      "desc": this.desc,
      "invt": this.invt,
      "codealt": this.codealt,
      "descalt": this.descalt,
      "group": this.group,
      "price": this.price,
      "disc1": this.disc1,
      "globalPrice": this.globalPrice,
      "total": this.total,
    };
  }

  ///get function to get the properties of Item
  dynamic get(String propertyName) {
    var _mapRep = toJson();
    if (_mapRep.containsKey(propertyName)) {
      return _mapRep[propertyName];
    }
    throw ArgumentError('propery not found');
  }
}
```

for the example data please check https://justpaste.it/1v8t8

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61673246/ for how to do stable sorts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the `comparable` interface for `CartItem` then in the `compareTo` function, you can check all the parameters that you want to sort by:

```dart
void main() {
  List<CartItem> cartItems = [...];
  cartItems.sort();
}

class CartItem implements Comparable<CartItem>{
  String qty;
  final String code;
  final String desc;
  final String invt;
  final String codealt;
  final String descalt;
  final String group;
  final String price;
  final String disc1;
  String globalPrice;
  String total;
  bool isSelected;

  CartItem(
      this.qty,
      this.code,
      this.desc,
      this.invt,
      this.codealt,
      this.descalt,
      this.group,
      this.price,
      this.disc1,
      this.globalPrice,
      this.total,
      {this.isSelected = false});

  factory CartItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return CartItem(
        json['qty'],
      json['code'],
      json['desc'],
      json['invt'],
      json['codealt'],
      json['descalt'],
      json['group'],
      json['price'],
      json['disc1'],
      json['globalPrice'],
      json['total'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "qty": this.qty,
      "code": this.code,
      "desc": this.desc,
      "invt": this.invt,
      "codealt": this.codealt,
      "descalt": this.descalt,
      "group": this.group,
      "price": this.price,
      "disc1": this.disc1,
      "globalPrice": this.globalPrice,
      "total": this.total,
    };
  }

  ///get function to get the properties of Item
  dynamic get(String propertyName) {
    var _mapRep = toJson();
    if (_mapRep.containsKey(propertyName)) {
      return _mapRep[propertyName];
    }
    throw ArgumentError('propery not found');
  }

  @override
  int compareTo(CartItem other) {
    // compare the groups
    final gc = group.compareTo(other.group);

    // if there are not equal gc will not be 0
    if (gc != 0) return gc;
    
    // if there are equal, then gc will be 0 so will go and compare codes
    final cc = code.compareTo(other.code);

    // return code compare result
    return cc;
  }
}
```

Another more functional way to archive this is like this:

```dart
void main() {
  List<CartItem> cartItems = [...];
  cartItems.sort((a, b) =>
      <Comparator<CartItem>>[
            (o1, o2) => o1.group.compareTo(o2.group),
            (o1, o2) => o1.code.compareTo(o2.code),
            // add more comparators here
      ].map((e) => e(a, b))
          .firstWhere((e) => e != 0,
          orElse: () => 0));
}
```

Comment: when I tested a single group on the list, It worked well but it didn't sort well when there were multiple groups. I will update the post with an example of the data.

Comment: please check the example data https://justpaste.it/1v8t8

Comment: I thought you wanted to sort by `code` and then `group`. edited my answer. but looking at your sample data if this doesn't work, you may need to parse `code`  and turn it into an integer before comparing.

Comment: sorry, I did state that I wanted to sort by `group` then by `code` but in the example of the hack I did I had to sort by `code` then by `group` in order for it to work as I wanted. How do you even turn `code` into int?

Comment: Something like this:`var codeNumber = '28113-A9100'.trim().toLowerCase().split('-').map((e) => BigInt.tryParse(e, radix: 32)).reduce((p1, p2) => (p1 << 40) + p2);`

Comment: it worked! your edited code works perfectly! I wonder if I should compute this? not sure if it might fail on large lists?