# How to sort data in flutter by descending order?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm new to flutter, I don't understand how to sort data in firebase in descending or ascending order. Here's the code. Thank you in advance.

```
Expanded(
        child: Container(
          width: size.width,
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 16.0),
          child: GridView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              childAspectRatio: 1 / 1.2,
              mainAxisSpacing: 16.0,
              crossAxisSpacing: 16.0,
            ),
            itemCount: widget.categoryList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return AllCategoryItem(
                category: widget.categoryList[index],
                index: index,
                cartBloc: widget.cartBloc,
                firebaseUser: widget.firebaseUser,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53547997/sort-a-list-of-objects-in-flutter-dart-by-property-value

Answer (score 0):

use `List.parse` function for example :

```
 someObjects.sort((a, b) => a.someProperty.compareTo(b.someProperty));
```

Comment: In this line of code " category: widget.categoryList[index]," ? Thanks man