# How to sort a list of objects by enum variable in the object in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to sort a list of Objects by an enum variable in the object in Dart?

for Example:

```dart
class Task {
final String name;
final Priority priority;
}

enum Priority {
first,
second,
third
}

List<Task> tasks; // <-- how to sort this list by its [Priority]?
```

Comment: Do you have to use an enum for priority? It would make much more sense to use an integer priority.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore you You are right, but assume we have a `List<Restaurant>` and each `Restaurant` have its `Status` `open`, `busy` or `closed` and we want to show open restaurants at first then busy then closed, that is my case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a list of objects in Flutter (Dart) by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53547997/sort-a-list-of-objects-in-flutter-dart-by-property-value)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```dart
class Task {
  final String name;
  final Priority priority;
  Task(this.name, this.priority);
  @override toString() => "Task($name, $priority)";
}

enum Priority {
  first,
  second,
  third
}

extension on Priority {
  int compareTo(Priority other) =>this.index.compareTo(other.index);
}

List<Task> tasks = [
  Task('zort', Priority.second),
  Task('foo', Priority.first),
  Task('bar', Priority.third),
];

main() {
  tasks.sort((a, b) => a.priority.compareTo(b.priority));
  print(tasks);
}
```

It assumes your enum is declared in the correct order for sorting.

Comment: You could have used a.priority.index in your sort callback, and not needed the extension. :)

Comment: Or, using the dartx package, which adds .sortBy to Lists, you could have said `tasks.sortBy((e) => e.priority.index);`

Comment: @RandalSchwartz oh of course :D I was going with an attempt to make Priority Comparable but extensions can't actually do that, unfortunately. Not that it would help much anyway. It would only if Dart already had `sortBy`, so it would look pretty `tasks.sortBy((t)=>t.priority)` but as you mention, you need a lib for that.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would use the official [`package:collection/collection.dart`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) package.

You then can just do it like that:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

// modify existing list
tasks.sortBy<num>((e) => e.priority.index);

// create sorted copy
final sortedTasks = tasks.sortedBy<num>((e) => e.priority.index);
```

*Note:* the `<num>` generic is required here, because `int` does not implement `Comparable<int>`. See here for more details why: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/43763

Answer (score 0):

Dart 2.17 and later makes it easier, just user members in the new  Enhanced Enums, For Example:

```dart
enum Priority {
first(1),
second(2),
third(3);
 const Priority(this.val);
final int val;
}

tasks.sort((a, b) => a.priority.val.compareTo(b.priority.val));
```