# How to sort the list of cards(according to the name) by clicking the sorting button in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, sorting

I have certain list of cards which are showing the user details and are unsorted. I want to sort them in ascending order according to the name of users by clicking on the sorting button.

I am doing state management so taking the help of **ChangeNotifier** . Here I tried the sorting functionality but getting Exception like : **type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'List'**

Can you please help me figuring out where I am doing wrong? I want to plot the cards in a ordered format as per the names. Here is my code:-

**patient.dart** :

```
class Patient {
  String name ;
  String imgPath ;
  int totalSession ;
  int completedSession ;
  String status ;
  String dob ;
  bool isActive ;

  Patient(this.name, this.imgPath,this.totalSession,this.completedSession,this.status,this.dob,this.isActive);

}
```

**patient_notifier.dart** :

```
class PatientDataNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
List<Patient> patient = [] ;

   PatientDataNotifier(){
     getPatient('All');
   }
 getPatient(String search) async{

    final List<Patient> patients = [
      Patient('Partha', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1545996124-0501ebae84d0?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OHx8aHVtYW58ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80',
          8, 2, 'Pending', '10-08-2015', true),
      Patient('Reenu', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544005313-94ddf0286df2?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTF8fGh1bWFufGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80',
          8, 5, 'Cancelled', '23-12-2019', false),
      Patient('Abhipsa', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554151228-14d9def656e4?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8aHVtYW58ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80',
          8, 7, 'Visited', '01-02-2019', false),
      Patient('Sushree', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Woman_7.jpg',
          8, 4, 'Pending', '20-09-2018', true),
      Patient('Arpita', 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/07/14/15/portrait-2604283__340.jpg',
          8, 6, 'Visited', '28-04-2017', false),
      Patient('Tanmay', 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/07/14/15/portrait-2604283__340.jpg',
          8, 6, 'Visited', '28-04-2017', false),
      Patient('Priyanka', 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/07/14/15/portrait-2604283__340.jpg',
          8, 6, 'Visited', '28-04-2017', false)
    ];

    if(search == 'All') {
      patient.clear();
      for(var i=0 ; i<patients.length ; i++){
        patient.add(patients[i]);
      }
}
    else{
      patient.clear();
     List<Patient> filteredPatients = filterPatients(patients , search);
     for(var i=0 ; i<filteredPatients.length ; i++){
       patient.add(filteredPatients[i]);
     }
    }


notifyListeners();
    return patients ;
  }

// Logic for sorting data according to name
sortData() {
    List<Patient> sortedList = getPatient("All");
    sortedList.sort((a,b) => a.name.compareTo(b.name));

    sortedList.forEach((patient) => print(patient.name));

    notifyListeners();

  }
}
```

**adminhome_content.dart** (the page containing the UI part) :

```
class AdminHomeContent extends StatelessWidget {

  final Map<String, Color> options = {
    'All': Colors.black, 'Cancelled':Colors.red,
    'Pending': Colors.lightGreen, 'Visited': Colors.green[900],
  };

  String selectedOption = 'All';
@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return ChangeNotifierProvider<PatientDataNotifier>(
        create: (context) => PatientDataNotifier(),
        child: MaterialApp(
            home: Scaffold(
              appBar: aapBarSection('Today\'s Appointments' , Colors.blueAccent[700], context),
              body: Container(
                   //codes for some Layouts
                ..............................
               ..........................
```

//code for the sorting icon

```
child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 25.0),
child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
           Consumer<PatientDataNotifier>(
              builder: (context, patientNotifier, _) {
                return IconButton(
                 icon: Icon(Icons.sort),
                 onPressed: () {
                patientNotifier.sortData();
         },
       );
   }
    )
  ],
 ),
```

),

```
Container(
                      child: Expanded(
                        child: Consumer<PatientDataNotifier>(
                            builder: (context, patientNotifier, _) {
                              return ListView.builder(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: patientNotifier.patient.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return getListItem(patientNotifier.patient[index], options);
                                },
                              );
                            }
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
getListItem(Patient patient, options){
    String status = patient.status;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
            
     -----------------
             -----------
```

Please help me solving it.

[here is my output. I am unable to sort the cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp6C9.jpg)

Comment: This might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53547997/sort-a-list-of-objects-in-flutter-dart-by-property-value

Comment: @ASADHAMEED thank you for helping.That worked

Comment: You're welcome :)
I would request you to remove this question if, you're question is a duplicate :)