# Dart - Best sort Algorithm for pushing a list of objects to a list of First Class Lists

Tags: algorithm, flutter, sorting, dart

I have a list of objects that are retrieved from a DB. The object looks like this:

```
class MonthlyFinancePlan {

  final int id;
  final DateTime date;
  final double incomeAfterTax;
  final double totalToPayOut;
  final double totalRemainingForMonth;
  final Map<String, dynamic> items;

  MonthlyFinancePlan({ this.id, this.date, this.incomeAfterTax, this.totalToPayOut, this.totalRemainingForMonth, this.items });

  MonthlyFinancePlan.fromEntity(MonthlyFinancePlanEntity monthlyFinancePlanEntity):
    this.id = monthlyFinancePlanEntity.id,
    this.date = DateTime.parse(monthlyFinancePlanEntity.date),
    this.incomeAfterTax = monthlyFinancePlanEntity.incomeAfterTax.toDouble(),
    this.totalToPayOut = monthlyFinancePlanEntity.totalToPayOut.toDouble(),
    this.totalRemainingForMonth = monthlyFinancePlanEntity.moneyRemainingForMonth.toDouble(),
    this.items = monthlyFinancePlanEntity.items != null ? json.decode(monthlyFinancePlanEntity.items) : Map();
}
```

I need to sort these by `date.year` and then pass them into a first class List, I'd like to create a List of these First class lists so that all the `MonthlyFinancePlan` objects that are from the year 2020 are sorted and contained within the first class list, same for 2021, etc.

The first class list looks like this:

```
class YearlyFinancePlan {

  List<MonthlyFinancePlan> _monthlyFinancePlanList;

  int _year;
  double _totalIncomeForYear;
  double _totalOutGoingsForYear;

  List<MonthlyFinancePlan> get items {
    return this._monthlyFinancePlanList;
  }

  int get year {
    return this._year;
  }

  double get totalIncomeForYear {
    return this._totalIncomeForYear;
  }

  double get totalOutgoingsForYear {
    return this._totalOutGoingsForYear;
  }

  YearlyFinancePlan(this._monthlyFinancePlanList) {
    this._year = this._monthlyFinancePlanList.first.date.year;
    this._totalIncomeForYear = this._setTotalIncomeFromList(this._monthlyFinancePlanList);
    this._totalOutGoingsForYear = this._setTotalOutGoingsForYear(this._monthlyFinancePlanList);
  }

  double _setTotalIncomeFromList(List<MonthlyFinancePlan> monthlyFinancePlanList) {
    double totalIncome;

    monthlyFinancePlanList.forEach((plan) => totalIncome += plan.incomeAfterTax);
    return totalIncome;
  }

  double _setTotalOutGoingsForYear(List<MonthlyFinancePlan> monthlyFinancePlanList) {
    double totalOutgoings;

    monthlyFinancePlanList.forEach((plan) => totalOutgoings += plan.totalToPayOut);
    return totalOutgoings;
  }
}
```

My question is, what sort algorithm would be best suited for what I need? I don't have any code to show as I don't know what sort algorithm to use. I'm not looking for anyone to write my code, but more to guide me through it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What does "first class List" mean?  Do you mean that you want a `List<YearlyFinancePlan>`, and each `YearlyFinancePlan` has a `List<MonthlyFinancePlan>`?  Instead of a `List<YearlyFinancePlan>`, I'd use a [`SplayTreeMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap-class.html) that maps each year to a `YearlyFinancePlan`, and it will keep those sorted for you.  From there you could iterate over all of your `MonthlyFinancePlan` and easily bin them into the appropriate `YearlyFinancePlan`.

Comment: And then if you need to further sort the `List<MonthlyFinancePlan>` within each `YearlyFinancePlan`, then just use the normal [`List.sort` with an appropriate callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53547997/)

Comment: By First Class list I mean an Object that contains a list of `MonthlyFinancePlan`, I'm not actually sure what the correct name for this type of object is (I've been searching for day). But yeah, the plan would be to have a list of `YearlyFinancePlan` that contains a sorted list of `MonthlyFinancePlan`. Each `MonthlyFinancePlan` would be sorted by year and then passed into an appropriate `YearlyFinancePlan` so when `YearlyFinancePlan.year()` is called I would expect it to return only 2020 (for example). I'll take a look at the SplayTreeMap now and post an answer when I've implemented the code!

Comment: @jamesdlin I've added an answer below

Answer (score 1):

I've created a Mapper that checks if the `MonthlyPlanner.date.year` exists as a key in a standard Dart Map and adds it if it doesn't exist. Once the check is complete, it also calls the `addMonthlyPlan` method to add the entry to the `MonthlyPlan` to the correct `YearlyPlan` like so:

```
class FinancePlanMapper {

  static Map<int, YearlyFinancePlan> toMap(List<MonthlyFinancePlan> planList) {
    Map<int, YearlyFinancePlan> planMap = Map();

    planList.forEach((monthlyPlan) {
      planMap.putIfAbsent(monthlyPlan.date.year, () => YearlyFinancePlan(List()));
      planMap[monthlyPlan.date.year].addMonthlyPlan(monthlyPlan);
    });

    return planMap;
  }

}
```

I'm not too sure whether it's the most efficient way of sorting but I plan to refactor it as much as possible. I've also updated the `YearlyFinancePlan` object so that it doesn't initialise any fields on construction, which would cause the object to throw an error when being initialised with an empty list:

```
class YearlyFinancePlan {

  List<MonthlyFinancePlan> _monthlyFinancePlanList;

  List<MonthlyFinancePlan> get items {
    return this._monthlyFinancePlanList;
  }

  int get year {
    return this.items.first.date.year;
  }

  double get totalIncomeForYear {
    return this._setTotalIncomeFromList(this._monthlyFinancePlanList);
  }

  double get totalOutgoingsForYear {
    return this._setTotalOutGoingsForYear(this._monthlyFinancePlanList);
  }

  YearlyFinancePlan(this._monthlyFinancePlanList);

  void addMonthlyPlan(MonthlyFinancePlan plan) {
    this._monthlyFinancePlanList.add(plan);
  }

  double _setTotalIncomeFromList(List<MonthlyFinancePlan> monthlyFinancePlanList) {
    double totalIncome = 0;

    monthlyFinancePlanList.forEach((plan) => totalIncome += plan.incomeAfterTax);
    return totalIncome;
  }

  double _setTotalOutGoingsForYear(List<MonthlyFinancePlan> monthlyFinancePlanList) {
    double totalOutgoings = 0;

    monthlyFinancePlanList.forEach((plan) => totalOutgoings += plan.totalToPayOut);
    return totalOutgoings;
  }
}
```