# Sort a list by custom property and then DateTime property

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of items that include a custom priority (Highest, High, Normal) and DateTime properties captured on user entry.

Example:

```
Entry(
  title: 'Hello!',
  author: 'Plato',
  notes: 'Are you working as hard as you can?',
  mlPriority: MlPriority.Highest,
  date: DateTime(2021, 2, 23, 12, 00),
),
```

I'm passing the list to `ListView` via a map to build Cards.

```
ListView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      child: Column(
        children: theReviewItems.map((e) {
          ...some if statements...Return CustomCardBuilderWidget
```

How do I sort the list first by priority (Highest, High, Normal) and then by descending DateTime before passing into my .map / Widget card builder?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61673246/

Comment: Thank you. Much better than the other explanations I came across.

Comment: Could you think about creating a `Map<MlPriority, List<Entry>>`?

Comment: By the way, what's the protocol here? Do I just delete this question? Seems pointless to keep around when the solution is to another post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a list of objects in Flutter (Dart) by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53547997/sort-a-list-of-objects-in-flutter-dart-by-property-value)

Comment: The protocol is to close your question as a duplicate of another question, but you can also delete it if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Example

```
final priorityMap = {
    MlPriority.Normal: 1,
    MlPriority.High: 2,
    MlPriority.Highest: 3,
  };
  
  // Sort by priority
  theReviewItems.sort((e1, e2) => priorityMap[e1.mlPriority] > priorityMap[e2.mlPriority] ? -1 : 1);
  
  // Sort by date
  theReviewItems.sort((e1, e2) {
    if (e1.mlPr
        iority == e2.mlPriority) return e2.date.compareTo(e1.date);
    return 0;
  });

// Print result
for (final item in theReviewItems) print('${item.mlPriority}: ${item.date}');
```