# Iterable extension case insensitive sorting

Tags: flutter, iterable

I copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60920035/13250142) SO answer using an extension for sorting.

```
extension IterableX<E> on Iterable<E> {
  Iterable<E> sortedBy(Comparable key(E e)) =>
      toList()..sort((a, b) => key(a).compareTo(key(b)));     
}
```

I am using it to sort alphabetically, but would like to make it case insensitive and I can't.

```
extension IterableX<E> on Iterable<E> {
  Iterable<E> caseInsensitiveSortedBy(Comparable key(E e)) => toList()
    ..sort((a, b) => key(a?.toUpperCase())
        .compareTo(key(b?.toUpperCase())));
}
```

is not allowed because `The method 'toUpperCase' isn't defined for the type '<unknown>'.`

So I am trying

```
Iterable<E> caseInsensitiveSortedBy(Comparable key(E e)) => toList()
    ..sort((a, b) =>
        key(a is String? ? a.toUpperCase() : a).compareTo(key(b is String? ? b.toUpperCase() : b)));
```

And I get `The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'E'.`

Comment: @pskink I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your extension should be applied to **only** `Iterable<String>`, not any iterable:

```dart
extension IterableX on Iterable<String> {
  Iterable<String> caseInsensitiveSortedBy() => toList()
    ..sort((a, b) => a.toUpperCase()
        .compareTo(b.toUpperCase()));
}
```

You cannot call `toUpperCase` on any type.

Comment: Why doesn't it work when type checking, like the third option?

Comment: @user3808307 In your example, you're doing a call to `get` which expects type `E`. When you're doing `.toUpperCase`, the type you're trying to call `get` with is changed from `E` to `String`. Even though *you* know that `toUpperCase` will only be called when `E` *is* `String`, the Dart type system doesn't know. That's what casts are for. So alternatively, you could use your third option and do `.toUpperCase() as E`.

Comment: @user3808307 I chose to restrict the extension to just string partially because I didn't pay close attention to your third example but mostly because it doesn't make sense to have `caseInsensitiveSortedBy` as a generic extension since it only makes sense on `String`s.