# How Can I Retrieve these data from Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, cross-platform

[image: Firestore Collection]

I want to get data from the map in firestore and display it in the List ordered by date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be a single document. You would have to [fetch](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#one-time-read) the whole document if you are just going to have a new map for each date. Then sort it yourself using dart.

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('BMI')
    .doc('docID')
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        print('Document exists on the database');
        // sort here

        List myList = documentSnapshot.data!.data().entries.map((entry) => entry).toList();
        print(myList);
        // sorting the list
        print(myList.sort((a, b) => a.date.compareTo(b.date)))
      }
    });
```

You can read more about sorting lists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53547997/sort-a-list-of-objects-in-flutter-dart-by-property-value). If you need to limit number of entries to be fetched then you would have create a dedicated documents for each entry.