# Dart List.sortedBy function with generic Comparable as parameter wont manipulate the list

Tags: list, flutter, dart, generics

I want to order objects in a List by the value of the objects instance variables and
i actually found exactly what I was looking for in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62008660/4420202
...and this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60920035/4420202 but no mather what my lists objects stays in the exact same order.

This is the extension:

```
extension MyIterable<E> on Iterable<E> {
  Iterable<E> sortedBy(Comparable key(E e)) =>
      toList()..sort((a, b) => key(a).compareTo(key(b)));
}
```

And this is how i use it:

```
list.sortedBy((it) => it.name);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't order the list itself. It returns a new iterable with all elements in order. Save it into a variable and then you can then iterate over that to get the all elements in order. If you want the result as a list you can use the `toList` method.