# Sorting List on multiple conditions

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show a List called listaBaresFiltrada, sorted on multiple values.

Evento model:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Evento {
  final String eventoId;
  final String fechaEvento;
  final String tituloEvento;
  final String evento;
  final bool es_privado;
  final bool es_publico;
  final String num_invitados;
  final String ubicacionEvento;
  final String latitudEvento;
  final String longitudEvento;
  final String descripcionEvento;
  final String imagenEvento;
  final String autorEvento;
  final String fotoPerfilAutor;
  final String interes;
   double distancia;
   bool menosde30km;
   bool espasado;
```

First I would like to sort on following values:

1. fechaEvento (DateTime ascending)
2. menosde30km (bool true)
3. distance (double)

For now I am able to make the firsto sorting condition, like follows:

```
//sorting the list
listaBaresFiltrada.sort((a,b) => 
DateFormat('d-M-yyyy HH:mm', 'de_DE').parse(a.fechaEvento).compareTo(
DateFormat('d-M-yyyy HH:mm', 'de_DE').parse(b.fechaEvento)));
```

But I don't know how to include both others sorting conditions.

Comment: Specifically, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61673246/) on the linked question which discusses sorting and subsorting on multiple properties and using a stable sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't sort a list with 3 different conditions I assume that you want to have 3 different list. For that you have to:

```
 List sortOne = listaBaresFiltrada.sort((a,b) => 
   if(a) return 1;
   else return -1
 );
 List sortTwo = listaBaresFiltrada.sort((a,b) => 
   DateFormat('d-M-yyyy HH:mm', 'de_DE').parse(a.fechaEvento).compareTo(DateFormat('d-M-yyyy HH:mm', 'de_DE').parse(b.fechaEvento))
 );
 List sortThree = listaBaresFiltrada.sort((a,b) => 
   a.distancia.compareTo(b.distancia)
 );
```

Comment: Using your proposal I am getting an error: The return type 'bool' isn't a 'int', as required by the closure's context

Comment: I edited my answer. I think this is the correct answer for your question. Best luck!