# How to sort List of instance class depend on its property in dart or flutter

Tags: list, flutter, class, sorting, dart

[image]
i have a `List<Contact>` where the class Contact like this below:

```
class Contact {
    Contact({
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.phone,
        this.job,
        this.company,
        this.image,
        this.email,
    });

    int? id;
    String? name;
    String? phone;
    String? job;
    String? company;
    String? image;
    String? email;

}
```

the question is, how to sort the List by comparing the Contact.name?
because i want sort the list ascending A-Z

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a comparison function to List.sort.

someObjects.sort((a, b) => a.someProperty.compareTo(b.someProperty));

or List mList = (mList..sort()).reversed.toList();

you can be helped from this link [Sort a list of objects in Flutter (Dart) by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53547997/sort-a-list-of-objects-in-flutter-dart-by-property-value)

Comment: okey, but i have try it, and the result is error like this The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Comment: how can i resolve that error?

Comment: @Dedi Your `.sort` callback will need to take check for `null`.  For example: `list.sort((a, b) { final aProperty= a.property; final bProperty = b.property; if (aProperty != null && bProperty != null) { return aProperty.compareTo(bProperty); } else if (aProperty == bProperty) { return 0; } else if (aProperty == null) { return -1; } else { return 1; })`.

Comment: Alternatively it would be a lot simpler if you could use empty strings instead of `null`, and then you wouldn't need to deal with `String?`.

Comment: thanks for your explanation @jamesdin