# How can I filter a list in Flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, sorting

I have a list like:

```
products=[{"name":"apple","qty":"5"},{"name":"apple","qty":"2"},{"name":"orange","qty":"3"},],
```

but I want a new list sorted list as follows:

```
products=[{"name":"apple","qty":"7"},{"name":"orange","qty":"3"}].
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a list of objects in Flutter (Dart) by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53547997/sort-a-list-of-objects-in-flutter-dart-by-property-value)

Comment: not exactly ...

Comment: use [groupBy](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/groupBy.html) to group your items by "name", then reduce the multiple names to single item and finally call `List.sort` method

Comment: could you please elaborate

Comment: this is the first step: `final grouped = groupBy(products, (i) => i['name']);` - here you have `products` grouped by "name"