# How to sort list of file in order of latest to oldest

Tags: flutter

Currently, I am fetching a list of video files present in the directory using the following code

```
var videoList = _videoDir
          .listSync()
          .map((item) => item.path)
          .where((item) => item.endsWith(".mp4"))
          .toList(growable: true);
```

This generates a video list in random order. How can I fetch files in order of latest to oldest?

## Update

I already tried to use the `startsync()` function at the end of the code but it cant be used on the type String when used after `.toList()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a list of objects in Flutter (Dart) by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53547997/sort-a-list-of-objects-in-flutter-dart-by-property-value)

Comment: I tried this as well but after generating the video list, it's in string form and I cant use the statSync method on it. i need files to be sorted according to the timestamp they where created i.e latest to oldest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stat()` or `statSync()` function of `File` class to sort the list in desired order.

```dart
  var videoList = videoDir.listSync()
    .where((e) => e.path.endsWith('.mp4'))
    .toList()
    ..sort((l, r) => l.statSync().modified.compareTo(r.statSync().modified));

  var videosPathList = videoList.map((e) => e.path).toList();
```

#### Note

- `List` is `growable` by default.
- 

```dart
List<FileSystemEntity> toList({bool growable = true})
dart:core

Creates a [List] containing the elements of this [Iterable].

The elements are in iteration order. The list is fixed-length if [growable] is false.
```

#### APIs:

- [FileStat](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.0/dart-io/FileStat-class.html)
- [File](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.0/dart-io/File-class.html) class

Comment: I tried the above method already but statSync() cant work on string its throwing an error when used in such a way that's the problem. how I can map and as well as sort in this case?

Comment: its working on my system. First sort, then map

Comment: Yes got it, now it's working it had to separate map and sorting! Thankyou for your valuable answer it saved my time