# android SharedPreferences order/sort by field

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i am retrieving all SharedPreferences inside my app like this:

```
getCollection() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (prefs.getInt("collectionCount") == null) {
      clearCollection();
    } else {
      collectionCount = prefs.getInt("collectionCount")!;
      url = prefs.getStringList("collectionUrl")!.reversed.toList();
      method = prefs.getStringList("collectionMethod")!.reversed.toList();
      headers = prefs.getStringList("collectionHeaders")!.reversed.toList();
      body = prefs.getStringList("collectionBody")!.reversed.toList();
      name = prefs.getStringList("collectionName")!.reversed.toList();
      syntax = prefs.getStringList("collectionSyntax")!.reversed.toList();
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to order the output by the name (collectionName) field in alphabetic order?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using reversed try with sort function.
Here some info about sort function (i think that language is dart): [Sort a list of objects in Flutter (Dart) by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53547997/sort-a-list-of-objects-in-flutter-dart-by-property-value)