# how to sort a list of data by ISO8601 format

Tags: flutter, list, sorting, datetime, iso8601

I've got a list of data which also contains **ISO8601** **DateTime** format. How can I sort it by time not date?

```
[2022-12-06T22:37:49.292343,
 2022-12-06T18:37:49.300045,
 2022-12-06T15:37:49.307976]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just clarify, you want to ignore the date part when sorting...

Answer (score 0):

To sort the list of dates by their *hour*, you can use:

```dart
void main() {
  final dates = [
    '2022-12-06T22:39:50.292343',
    '2022-12-06T18:37:49.300045',
    '2022-12-06T15:37:49.307976'
  ];
  
  dates
      .sort((a, b) => DateTime.parse(a).hour.compareTo(DateTime.parse(b).hour));
  print(dates);
}
```

Output:

```
[2022-12-06T15:37:49.307976, 2022-12-06T18:37:49.300045, 2022-12-06T22:39:50.292343]
```

Comment: this works however, could we improvise it a bit and compare whole ISO8601 for sorting.. if not date then time else minutes or second!

Answer (score 0):

1. Parse the strings to `DateTime` objects.
2. If you want to ignore the date and sort only by time, create new `DateTime` objects that copy the times and that all use the same date.
3. Sort by those new `DateTime` objects.

```dart
void main() {
  var dateTimeStrings = [
    '2022-12-01T22:37:49.292343',
    '2022-12-02T18:37:49.300045',
    '2022-12-03T15:37:49.307976',
  ];

  /// Replaces the date portion of a [DateTime] with a fixed date,
  /// retaining the time portion.
  ///
  /// The returned [DateTime] object will be in UTC.
  ///
  /// In Dart 2.19, this implementation can be simplified with the
  /// [DateTime.copyWith] extension.
  DateTime clobberDate(DateTime dateTime) => DateTime.utc(
    2022,
    1,
    1,
    dateTime.hour,
    dateTime.minute,
    dateTime.second,
    dateTime.millisecond,
    dateTime.microsecond,
  );
  
  dateTimeStrings.sort((a, b) {
    var dt1 = clobberDate(DateTime.parse(a));
    var dt2 = clobberDate(DateTime.parse(b));
    return dt1.compareTo(dt2);
  });
  
  dateTimeStrings.forEach(print);
}
```

which prints:

```
2022-12-03T15:37:49.307976
2022-12-02T18:37:49.300045
2022-12-01T22:37:49.292343
```

Note that the above `sort` callback could be unnecessarily expensive for long lists since it could call `DateTime.parse` multiple times on the same `String`s.  It'd be better to convert your `List<String>` to a `List<DateTime>` first and then sort that.  Or, if you must start and end with `String`s, you could [use a Schwartzian transform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61673246/).