# How to sort a list twice in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to sort the list twice.

Example list (here is an example list with models):

```
[Model("A", 5), Model("C", 3), Model("B", 7) Model("F", 5), Model("D", 5)]
```

What I want is to sort alphabetically and then numerically. If I do this, I get the following result:

```
[Model("C", 3), Model("A", 5), Model("D", 5) Model("F", 5), Model("B", 7)]
```

Else:

Sort alphabetically:

```
[Model("A", 5), Model("B", 7), Model("C", 3) Model("D", 5), Model("F", 5)]
```

Sort numerically:

```
[Model("C", 3), Model("A", 5), Model("F", 5) Model("D", 5), Model("B", 7)]
```

My code:

```
Stream<List<T>> function<T>({
  …
  int Function(T lhs, T rhs) sort,
}) {
  …
  List<T> result = …;
  result.sort(sort);
}
```

---

```
Stream<List<Model>> stream() {
  return function(
    …
    sort: (a, b) => a.alphabet.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.alphabetc.toLowerCase())
  );
}
```

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more information.

How to sort a list twice? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: "How to sort a list twice?" you cannot, you need 2 lists then

Comment: Hi @pskink thanks for your comment. Can you answer this question and explain how to do it?

Comment: I don't think I can do it. I wrote the code to sort the list and the function code to sort in different places. I have shared the code

Comment: I covered how to sort by multiple properties (or alternatively, how to perform multiple *stable* sorts) in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61673246/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call it twice after each other like this:

```
modelList.sort(
  (a, b) => a.alphabet.compareTo(b.alphabet),
);
modelList.sort(
  (a, b) => a.number.compareTo(b.number),
);
```

in your case:

```
Stream<List<T>> function<T>({
  …
  
  int Function(T lhs, T rhs) sort1,
  int Function(T lhs, T rhs) sort2,
}) {
  …
  List<T> result = …;
  result.sort(sort1);
  result.sort(sort2);
}
```

result :

```
for (var element in modelList) {
  print("element = ${element.alphabet}"); //C, A, D, F, B
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! Although the result is correct, I don't think I can do it. I wrote the code to sort the list and the function code to sort in different places. I have shared the code

Comment: you can pass two sort. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it works! Thanks again!

Comment: `List.sort` is not guaranteed to be a stable sort.  You should not use it for subsorting.

Comment: @jamesdlin cold you explain more? or refer to some doc?

Comment: The [`List.sort` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/sort.html) explicitly states: "The sort function is not guaranteed to be stable, so distinct objects that compare as equal may occur in any order in the result:"

Comment: You are right but I think because in equal object it may return different result, My Car wants to sort it in two way that he make sure a bout that. @jamesdlin

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, first, implement the `Comparable` class on you `Model` class, and implement the `compareTo` method like this:

```
class Model implements Comparable {
  final String char;
  final int number;

  Model(this.char, this.number);

  @override
  toString() {
    return "Model('$char', '$number')";
  }
  
  @override
  int compareTo(other) {

    if (other is Model) {
      if (number == other.number) {
        return other.char.compareTo(char);
      } else {
        return other.number.compareTo(number);
      }
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Then, taking this example

```
List<Model> a = [
    Model("A", 5),
    Model("C", 3),
    Model("B", 7),
    Model("F", 5),
    Model("D", 5),
  ];
```

Trying to sort it will get you to your desired result:

```
a.sort((a, b) => b.compareTo(a) );
print(a); // [Model('C', '3'), Model('A', '5'), Model('D', '5'), Model('F', '5'), Model('B', '7')]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! I tested it and it works!

Comment: `List.sort` sorts in-place, so there'd be no additional space complexity from calling it multiple times.  Technically there'd be no additional time complexity in big-O terms either; O(2 * n log n) is still O(n log n).  In terms of real-world efficiency, it's not necessarily true that sorting multiple times is strictly slower than making your sort callback twice as long.  Calling `sort` twice would have more overhead, but I think it could be faster in some special cases where it has better cache locality.  If performance matters, benchmark and profile.

Comment: you're totally right, I will Edit the answer, I always learn new things from you, thank you a lot.