# Sort a list of objects by multiple conditions in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to sort a `personArray` with `age` **and** `name`:

```dart
final personArray = [
  _Person(age: 10, name: 'Dean'),
  _Person(age: 20, name: 'Jack'),
  _Person(age: 30, name: 'Ben'),
  _Person(age: 30, name: 'Alice'),
];
personArray.sort((p1, p2) {
  return Comparable.compare(p1.age, p2.age);
});
for (final element in personArray) {
  print(element.name);
}
```

Console print: Dean Jack Ben Alice.

But what I want is: Dean Jack Alice Ben.

The **pseudocode** looks like:

```dart
personArray.sort((p1, p2) {
  return Comparable.compare(p1.age, p2.age) && Comparable.compare(p1.name, p2.name);
});
```

Anyway can do it?

Comment: There are many existing questions about this.  Also see [my answer to "Sort a list of objects in Flutter (Dart) by property value"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61673246/) which covers this topic among various other sorting topics.

Comment: It's not the same at all. @jamesdlin

Comment: In the answer I linked to, I described three approaches for sorting by multiple properties (using stable sorts, combining comparison functions, and using `Comparator.then`).  Can you elaborate how that is not the same as what you're asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your compare function

```
personArray.sort((p1, p2) {
      final compare = Comparable.compare(p1.age, p2.age);
      return compare == 0 ? Comparable.compare(p1.name, p2.name) : compare;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code

```
  personArray.sort((a, b) {
  return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
  });
```

it will sort the objects with respect to name.

```
  personArray.sort((a, b) {
if (a.age != b.age) {
  return a.age - b.age;
}  else {
  return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
}
});
```

and this will sort it first with age and if both the age are equal then it will sort the objects with respect to name.

Comment: you can check the full program in the dartpad here https://dartpad.dev/?id=6bdd4917b2ad7dad791d521f3869e579