# How to sort model data received from JSON using flutter_bloc?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I have a model:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

Forecast forecastFromJson(String str) => Forecast.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String forecastToJson(Forecast data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Forecast {
  List<ListElement> list;

  Forecast({
    required this.list,
  });

  factory Forecast.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Forecast(
    list: List<ListElement>.from(json["list"].map((x) => ListElement.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "list": List<dynamic>.from(list.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class ListElement {
  int dt;
  Main main;
  DateTime dtTxt;

  ListElement({
    required this.dt,
    required this.main,
    required this.dtTxt,
  });

  factory ListElement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ListElement(
    dt: json["dt"],
    main: Main.fromJson(json["main"]),
    dtTxt: DateTime.parse(json["dt_txt"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "dt": dt,
    "main": main.toJson(),
    "dt_txt": dtTxt.toIso8601String(),
  };
}

class Main {
  double temp;
  int humidity;

  Main({
    required this.temp,
    required this.humidity,
  });

  factory Main.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Main(
    temp: json["temp"]?.toDouble(),
    humidity: json["humidity"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "temp": temp,
    "humidity": humidity,
  };
}
```

And there is a part of the code that outputs a list:

```dart
return  ListView.separated(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  itemCount: state.forecast.list.length,
                  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                        title: Text("${state.forecast.list[index].main.temp}", style:TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
                        subtitle: Text("${state.forecast.list[index].dtTxt}")
                    );
                  }
              );
```

Everything works great. But I need to make sure that the very first element of the list is the one with the lowest temperature.

That is, by default, the list items are sorted by date. And I need them to be sorted by temperature. And I do not need a button for sorting. I need the user to see a list sorted by temperature.

**Edit 1.** This is the code related to this state.

```dart
class ForecastLoadSuccess extends WeatherState {
  final Forecast forecast;

  ForecastLoadSuccess({required this.forecast});
}
```

**Edit 2.** This is the bloc code.

```
on<ForecastRequest>((event, emit) async {
    emit(WeatherLoadInProgress());
    try {
      final forecastResponse =
      await _forecastRepository.getForecast(event.cityName);
      emit(ForecastLoadSuccess(forecast: forecastResponse));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      emit(WeatherLoadFailure(error: e.toString()));
    }
  }
  );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53547997/sort-a-list-of-objects-in-flutter-dart-by-property-value

Comment: I found that thread before asking my question. Unfortunately, I don't understand how to apply this to my code. That's why I created this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
  factory Forecast.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Forecast(
    list: List<ListElement>.from(json["list"].map((x) => ListElement.fromJson(x))),
  );
```

To:

```
  factory Forecast.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Forecast(
    list: List<ListElement>.from(json["list"].map((x) => ListElement.fromJson(x)))..sort((a, b) => a.main.temp.compareTo(b.main.temp)),
  );
```

Notice that you probably want to do the sorting when you assign your state, and not in the `fromJson` method (what happens if the data comes from a different source? You will have to duplicate the code) but you didn't expose that part of the code.

**Edit**

By looking at your code, you can do something like this:

```
final forecastResponse = await _forecastRepository.getForecast(event.cityName);
forecastResponse.list.sort((a, b) => a.main.temp.compareTo(b.main.temp));
emit(...)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. You are absolutely right. Your advice is working. But I also want to know how to do it when I assign my state. I added this piece of code to Edit 1. Look at it, please.

Comment: not exactly. in your bloc, I guess you do `emit(forecast: ...)` I'm talking about that part. you should do it there

Comment: I added this piece of code to Edit 2. Please fix it. When I add ```sort((a, b) => a.main.temp.compareTo(b.main.temp))``` there, I get an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this, It will apply to all scenario

```
factory Forecast.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   final list = List<ListElement>.from(json["list"].map((x) => ListElement.fromJson(x)));
   list.sort((a,b)=> a.main.temp-b.main.temp);
   return Forecast(list: list);
}
```

or if you want to do it for a particular state, then pass that list to that state and sort it in that state class, for Example

```
class SomeState extends MainState {
  final List<ListElement> listOfElement;
  SomeState(this.listOfElement){
    listOfElement.sort((a,b)=> a.main.temp-b.main.temp);
  }
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't quite understand how to do this when I assign my state. I added this piece of code to Edit1. Look at it, please.