# How do write an algorithm that sorts notifications from oldest to newest

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a notifications page with three categories; `New`, `This Week` and `Oldest`. The notifications in `New` are notifications that came in on the the current day, the ones in `This week` are those that were received within the seven days. And the `Oldest` are all which are older than a week.

The time in which they were received is also attached to the notification.

How do I implement this?

Comment: If you know [how to sort a `List`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53547997/), this should be completely straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, as jamesdlin mentioned, you need a list. It would be easy if you shared your code. here is an example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class NotificationItem {
  String title;
  DateTime time;

  NotificationItem({required this.title, required this.time});
}

class NotificationsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const NotificationsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NotificationsPageState createState() => _NotificationsPageState();
}

class _NotificationsPageState extends State<NotificationsPage> {
  List<NotificationItem> _notifications = [
    NotificationItem(
        title: 'New notification 1', time: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(hours: 1))),
    NotificationItem(
        title: 'New notification 2', time: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(minutes: 30))),
    NotificationItem(
        title: 'This week notification 1', time: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 3))),
    NotificationItem(
        title: 'This week notification 2', time: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 6))),
    NotificationItem(
        title: 'Old notification 1', time: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 10))),
    NotificationItem(
        title: 'Old notification 2', time: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 14))),
  ];

  List<NotificationItem> get _newNotifications {
    return _notifications.where((notification) =>
        notification.time.isAfter(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1)))).toList();
  }

  List<NotificationItem> get _thisWeekNotifications {
    return _notifications.where((notification) =>
        notification.time.isAfter(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 7))) &&
        notification.time.isBefore(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1)))).toList();
  }

  List<NotificationItem> get _oldestNotifications {
    return _notifications.where((notification) =>
        notification.time.isBefore(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 7)))).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Notifications'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          _buildCategory('New', _newNotifications),
          _buildCategory('This Week', _thisWeekNotifications),
          _buildCategory('Oldest', _oldestNotifications),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCategory(String title, List<NotificationItem> notifications) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
        Divider(),
        ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: notifications.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(notifications[index].title),
              subtitle: Text(DateFormat('EEE, MMM d, yyyy - h:mm a').format(notifications[index].time)),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```