# Use a record/tuple as a key in a SplayTreeMap

Tags: flutter, dart

### Background

I'd like to be able to make a SplayTreeMap with the keys being tuples and the values being a list of maps. It would look something like the following:

```dart
{
   (1, 2023): [
         {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bob"
         },
         {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Alice"
         },
    ],
   (3, 2023): [
         {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Charlie"
         },
         {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Diana"
         },
    ]
}
```

---

So far I've just been experimenting in dart pad to make sure I get it right and I would have thought the following would have worked.

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  var invoicesST = SplayTreeMap();

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  invoicesST[(i, i+2000)] = [];

      invoicesST.update(
          [(i, i+2000)],
          (value) => [
                ...invoicesST[(i, i+2000)],
                {
                  'scId': 'sc$i',
                  'year': i+2000,
                  'week': i,
                  'month': i
                }
              ]);
    
          invoicesST.update(
          [(i, i+2000)],
          (value) => [
                ...invoicesST[(i, i+2000)],
                {
                  'scId': 'sc$i',
                  'year': i+2000,
                  'week': i+1,
                  'month': i
                }
              ]);
  }
  
  print(invoicesST);
}
```

But the output is the error  `TypeError: Record (0, 2000): type '(int, int)' is not a subtype of type 'Comparable<dynamic>'Error: TypeError: Record (0, 2000): type '(int, int)' is not a subtype of type 'Comparable<dynamic>'`. So records are not extending `Comparable` I guess?

I thought I would make my own and did the following but ultimately with the same error.

```dart
class MonthYear<T1, T2> {
  final T1 month;
  final T2 year;

  MonthYear(this.month, this.year);
  
  @override
  bool operator ==(other) {
    return (other is MonthYear)
        && other.month == month
        && other.year == year;
  }
  
  @override
  int get hashCode => month.hashCode ^ year.hashCode;
}
```

### Question

Is there a way to make this work or at least something similar? I'm not married to the idea of using the record type but it seemed like the best originally.

#### Sidenote

I'm using `SplayTreeMap` because I want to be able to sort the keys by descending order.

##### EDIT:

It just occured to me that I could use `DateTime` as a key with the way my data is but again the same error of `...is not a subtype of Comparable`

---

#### End result

Please read [the marked solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77498242/3030870) by @jamesdlin there's so much useful information there. I thought I would add the code that I settled on for consistency.

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  var invoicesST = SplayTreeMap<DateTime, List>();

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var example = {'scId': 'sc$i', 'year': i + 2000, 'week': i, 'month': i};

    invoicesST.update(
        DateTime(i+2000, i),
        (value) => [
              ...(invoicesST[DateTime(i+2000, i)] ?? []), example
            ], ifAbsent: () => [example]);
  }
  
  print(invoicesST);
}
```

A `DateTime` is used as the key but I was using it incorrectly as mentioned in *EDIT* and also the way I was using `update()`.

Comment: check the official `SplayTreeMap` docs, that say: "If the compare function is omitted, the objects are assumed to be Comparable, and are compared using their Comparable.compareTo method" - you can refer to `splay_tree.dart` source file and see `_defaultCompare` function (line 279 or so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [pskink explained in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77497967/#comment136624985_77497967), [`SplayTreeMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap-class.html) either expects the keys to be [`Comparable`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Comparable-class.html) or that the `SplayTreeMap` is constructed with an explicit comparison function.  You therefore can do:

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

typedef MonthYear = (int, int);

int compareMonthYear(MonthYear monthYear1, MonthYear monthYear2) {
  var (month1, year1) = monthYear1;
  var (month2, year2) = monthYear2;

  if (year1 < year2) {
    return -1;
  } else if (year1 > year2) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (month1 < month2) {
    return -1;
  } else if (month1 > month2) {
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}

void main() {
  var invoicesST = SplayTreeMap<MonthYear, List>(compareMonthYear);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    invoicesST[(i, i + 2000)] = [];

    invoicesST.update(
        (i, i + 2000),
        (value) => [
              ...(invoicesST[(i, i + 2000)] ?? []),
              {'scId': 'sc$i', 'year': i + 2000, 'week': i, 'month': i}
            ]);

    invoicesST.update(
        (i, i + 2000),
        (value) => [
              ...(invoicesST[(i, i + 2000)] ?? []),
              {'scId': 'sc$i', 'year': i + 2000, 'week': i + 1, 'month': i}
            ]);
  }

  print(invoicesST);
}
```

I made a few other corrections to the code, notably:

- Added explicit type arguments to the `SplayTreeMap` constructor.
- The calls to `invoicesST.update` incorrectly wrapped the `MonthYear` records in a `List`.
- The `invoicesST[(i, i + 2000)]` lookup might potentially fail and return `null`, and you cannot use the spread operator (`...`) on that.

> I thought I would make my own and did the following but ultimately with the same error.

Your explicit `MonthYear` class implementation completely neglects to implement the `Comparable` interface (as explained by the error message).  You could fix that by providing an explicit comparison callback or, since you control the `MonthYear` class:

```dart
class MonthYear<T1, T2> implements Comparable<MonthYear> {
  ...

  @override
  int compareTo(MonthYear other) {
    if (year < other.year) {
      return -1;
    } else if (year > other.year) {
      return 1;
    }

    if (month < other.month) {
      return -1;
    } else if (month > other.month) {
      return 1;
    }

    return 0;
  }
}
```

(Also see [Sort a list of objects in Flutter (Dart) by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61673246/).)

Note that the above comparison functions will sort dates in *ascending* order.  If you want descending order, you can make the comparison functions return negated values, or you can just reverse the output.

> It just occured to me that I could use `DateTime` as a key with the way my data is but again the same error of `...is not a subtype of Comparable`

You haven't shown your attempt at using `DateTime`, but [`DateTime`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) *does* implement the `Comparable` interface, so you did something else wrong:

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  var map  = SplayTreeMap<DateTime, String>();
  map[DateTime(2000, 1, 1)] = 'Hello';
  map[DateTime(2001, 1, 2)] = 'world';
  print(map);
}
```

Comment: By the time you need this many hoops jumped through, you might as well just have a real object.  Records are deliberately limited so that you don't do stuff like this. :)

Comment: What an amazing answer. Thank you so much for teaching so much so concisely.

In the end, I used a combination of your solutions and examples which I'll add to the original question for future people.