How to sort datatable 2 columns
I am using Flutter datatable class.
I need to sort each table column.
I created the class:
class myTest {
  late String Column1;
  late int Column2;
  late DateTime Column3;
  myTest({required this.Column1, required this.Column2, required this.Column3});
}

I want to use this class to sort my datatable.
I create datatable dynamically(using Future) like this:
Future<List<DataRow>> getMyInfo() async {

    for(var x in await myList()) {
      if(x.isNotEmpty){
        myDataRow.add(DataRow2(cells: <DataCell>[
          DataCell(Text(Column1)),
          DataCell(Text(Column2)),
          DataCell(Text(Column3)),
        ]));
      }
    }
    return myDataRow;
  }

I do not know how to sort using DataRow on each column.
I need to figure out how to use the above class to sort each table column.
I will sort column here:
var myColumns = [
      DataColumn(
        label:  Text('Column1'),
        onSort: (columnIndex, sortAscending) {
          setState(() {
            if (columnIndex == sortColumnIndex) {
              sortAsc = sortColumn1Asc = sortAscending;
            } else {
              sortColumnIndex = columnIndex;
              sortAsc = sortColumn1Asc;
            }

The code below on myDataRow is not working b/c I cannot figure out how to use my class above: There is no Column1 for a and b below.
  myDataRow.sort((a, b) => a.Column1.compareTo(b.Column1));
            if (!sortAsc) {
              myDataRow = myDataRow.reversed.toList();
            }
          });
        },
      ),

Could you please help.
Thank You

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53547997/sort-a-list-of-objects-in-flutter-dart-by-property-value this article may help
