# How to sort a string list alphabetically in Dart language?

Tags: string, list, sorting, dart

I have 4 companies and each company has more than 10 branches.
If a user chooses a company, I need to show the selected company branch using `showDialog`. Till here everything work as expected. My problem is that I cannot sort `List<String>` alphabetically.

Any idea how to sort string list (List) alphabetically in Dart?

```
List<String> _myBranchListName;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675055/sort-list-by-alphabetical-order

Comment: @JordanDavies the solution you provide is for List<dynamics>. It doesn't work for List<String>, thanks

Comment: @AlexanderFink, the solution you provide is for List<dynamics>. It doesn't work for List<String>, thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

- Flutter is an application development SDK
- Dart is a general-purpose programming language
- Flutter application is written in Dart
- so:

  > How to sort A to Z in Flutter List< String > ?
- Will be

  > How to sort A to Z in Dart List< String > ?
- A to Z : is called alphabetically so :

  > How to sort alphabetically in Dart List< String > ?
- List< String > : is a list of type string 
  so

  > How to sort alphabetically in Dart String List?
- more

  > How to sort a string list alphabetically in Dart language?

Code:

```
main() {
  List<String> _myBranchListName= ['k branch', 'a branch', 'f branch'];

  _myBranchListName.sort();
  print(_myBranchListName);

  //[a branch, f branch, k branch]
}
```

#### update

> I have a custom list with menas list contain class produt and product contain varable title and now i need to short my list based on title how to do it'''
>   [image: comment]

- base on [sort method - List class - dart:core library - Dart API](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/List/sort.html)

> sort method:
>
> Sorts this list according to the order specified by the compare function.
>
> The default List implementations use Comparable.compare if compare is omitted.
>
> A Comparator may compare objects as equal (return zero),
>
> even if they are distinct objects. The sort function is
>
> not guaranteed to be stable, so distinct objects that
>
> compare as equal may occur in any order in the result

- your code (Waring: i did not test this code i need your feedback):

`produts.sort((a, b) => a.title.compareTo(b.title));`

Comment: In my project I have more than 100 List<dynamic> which works with other solution that Jordan and Alexander provided. I have only one List<String> and I forget to use basic .sort(). Thanks for the info also

Comment: i have a custom list with menas list contain class produt and product contain varable title and now i need to short my list based on title how to do it?

Comment: @Midhilaj see the update in the Answer

Comment: Please note that the default comparison of two Strings is case-sensitive, which means that a String that starts with a lowercase "a" will come after one with an uppercase "Z". In my case I did not want that, so I fixed it like this: `a.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 5):

List Contains method called sort, that function will sort the list in alphabetical order (from a to z).

I created function for you to make the process more clear:

```
List<String> sort(List<String> _myBranchListName){    // This function take List of strings and return it organized alphabetically
 // List<String> _myBranchListName = ["B branch", "C branch" , "A branch"]; // example of input
  print(_myBranchListName);   // will show the result in the run log
  _myBranchListName.sort();
  print(_myBranchListName);   // will show the result in the run log
  return _myBranchListName;
}
```

Technically you only need `_myBranchListName.sort()` to sort the array.

Comment: thanks guy, .sort() is the solution

Comment: Hi @Nick if this answer has solved your question please click `This answer is useful` by clicking the check-mark. This will show you appreciation for the help.